# set the cursor to search view automatically

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have a button in an activity, on clicking that button, I direct the user to a search activity with a search view in the toolbar..

I'm using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`, I managed to expand it automatically using `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`..
I also open the keypad automatically in activity `onCreate`, yet I still have to click in the searchView to start typing there, I want the cursor to be set there automatically..

any help?

Comment: what you set automatically, as in ?

Answer (score 1):

call  `setIconifiedByDefault(false)` when the searchview is intialized.

> Sets the default or resting state of the search field. If true, a single search icon is shown by default and expands to show the text field and other buttons when pressed. Also, if the default state is iconified, then it collapses to that state when the close button is pressed. Changes to this property will take effect immediately.

Try the below, it worked for me once.

```
   searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
   searchView.setFocusable(true);
   searchView.setIconified(false);
   searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Update: If you are Using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` the behaviour is very different. `clearFocus` is needed if you don’t want the keyboard pop-up all the time.

> Also in the searchview layout, use  `<requestFocus />` tag.

Comment: yes the searchview is expanded, yet no cursor is there!

Comment: set setFocusable  to true, on searchView instance

Comment: any difference in focus ?